# Submit formlayout?

Tags: java, frameworks, vaadin, vaadin7

I've a FormLayout in my project, in this FormLayout I've one field email that I use EmailValidator to validate and one Button("Save").

When I enter with email on field email the validate is work and mark the field with (!) red if there any error.

How to I can check formlayout when I click on Button("Save") if there any field with validate error(!) the formlayout not be submited ?

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this chapter [here](https://vaadin.com/book/vaadin7/-/page/datamodel.itembinding.html)
and at the source code in the `basic()` method [here](http://dev.vaadin.com/svn/doc/book-examples/branches/vaadin-7/src/com/vaadin/book/examples/component/properties/RequiredExample.java).